# How to change object properties name when serialize?

Tags: java, json, serialization

I have an object like this.

```
public class Profile {
  private String email;
  private String phone;

  @SerializedName("userCode")
  private String user_code;

  public String getEmail() {
      return email;
  }

  public String getPhone() {
      return phone;
  }

  public String getUser_code() {
      return user_code;
  }
}
```

This is what I got when I return that object in Rest API

```
{
   "email": "abc@gmail.com",
   "phone": 12345678,
   "user_code": "742aeaefac"
}
```

Apparently annotation `@SerializedName` here did not work, I can understand that it get the object properties name base on its getter name, not in the annotation. If I change the getter name into `getUserCode()`, it will work as I expected.

I also try to use `@JsonProperty` but didn't help too.

Can someone explain what is the work here to solve this?

Update the code for serialization process in the controller.

```
@PostMapping(path = "/login", produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public ClientRepresentation login(@RequestBody LoginRequest login) {
    Map<String, Object> resObj = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    ProfileResponse profileResponse = userService.findUserProfileByUserCode(login.getUserCode());

    //Code logic to process object data...

    resObj.put("profile", profileResponse);

    return ClientRepresentationBuilder.buildClientRep(HttpStatus.OK.value(), "Success", resObj);
}
```

ClientRepresentation class

```
public class ClientRepresentation implements Serializable {
    private Integer code;
    private String message;
    private Object data;
}
```

Comment: There are different JSON libraries which can handle this issue differently. Which one are you using? Also how does your code responsible for serialization looks like?

Comment: Further, how can you return a `String` while `user_code` is `Boolean`?

Comment: JsonProperty should handle this use case. Can you show your code using JsonProperty?

Comment: I updated the code as you guys need.